# Interacting with a tooltip in d3js v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm creating a proof of concept in v4 of D3JS. One of the things I'm trying to do is have a tooltip display when hovering over a data point. I found a good example of this [here](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/257c360b3650b9f0a52dd8257d7a2d73).

What I now need to do is add a link (or any clickable element) to the tooltip. I created a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Z2zPzIPYXI9pgpa1WFT3) based on the example above and added a link to the tooltip. I can't click on the link and the tooltip appears to be below the line-chart as far as z-index goes.

I've tried setting the z-index on the chart and the tooltip to no avail. Can anyone point me in the right direction to sort this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 2px;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  background: lightsteelblue;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

</style>
<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// parse the date / time
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");
var formatTime = d3.timeFormat("%e %B");

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

// define the line
var valueline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

// append the svg obgect to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

// Get the data
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseTime(d.date);
      d.close = +d.close;
  });

  // scale the range of the data
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

  // add the valueline path.
  svg.append("path")
     .data([data])
     .attr("class", "line")
     .attr("d", valueline);

  // add the dots with tooltips
  svg.selectAll("dot")
     .data(data)
   .enter().append("circle")
     .attr("r", 5)
     .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
     .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.close); })
     .on("mouseover", function(d) {
       div.transition()
         .duration(200)
         .style("opacity", .9);
       div.html(formatTime(d.date) + "<br/>" + d.close + "<br/><a href='www.google.com'>Test it</a>")
         .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
         .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
       });

  // add the X Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // add the Y Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

});

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Just remove `pointer-events:none` in your tooltip CSS: https://plnkr.co/edit/xfa8cjQd3tHYNu0dUla4?p=preview

Comment: @GerardoFurtado That was it, thanks! If you add this as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating your tooltip based on the example in the link, you copied its CSS:

```
div.tooltip {
    pointer-events: none;
    ...
}
```

The reason we generally set `pointer-events` to `none` in a `<div>` tooltip, as the linked example did, is that we want to get the `mouseout` event on the element that fired the `mouseover` (normally to set the tooltip's opacity to zero), and if the tooltip is positioned to close from the element (sometimes even directly over it) the pointer can hover over the div and ruin the `mouseout`. Besides that, another important reason to set `pointer-events` to `none` is that it allows other elements behind the tooltip to get `mouseover` events, just like if the tooltip was not there.

However, because in your code there is no `mouseout`, the easier solution here is simply eliminating the `pointer-events: none` in the CSS. That way the `<div>` get the `click` event.

This is the updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/xfa8cjQd3tHYNu0dUla4?p=preview